# Database Transaction Date and Time Changing with New Timezone

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am working on a travel app that logs date and time with other data. Upon return from Frankfurt (Central European Summer Time) to the US west coast (Pacific Datelight Time) (9 hours difference) recently I noticed that all the transaction dates and times have been adjusted for the new timezone. So many transactions are showing up as taking place at two or three in the morning.

Is there a way to maintain the local date and time without converting them to the new timezone? Is the problem with the display of the data such as not correctly handling UTC?

I am using the DatePicker() to read in the date and time, then saving it to coreData without any special processing.

```
struct getFormData: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy

    @Binding var entryDT: Date

    var body: some View {

        // get entry date and time
        HStack (spacing: 0) {
            Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
                .resizable()
                .foregroundColor(Color("myRed"))
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)

            Spacer()

            DatePicker("", selection: $entryDT, in: ...Date())
                .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
        }
        .padding(.bottom, UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? 10 : 25)
```

```
 // the save button has been pressed
    func saveButton() {

        // save entry to core data
        let newEntry = CurrTrans(context: viewContext)

        // entry id
        newEntry.id = UUID()

        // entry date
        newEntry.entryDT = entryDT

        do {
            try viewContext.save()

        } catch {

        }
```

Below is how I display a transaction the date and time. So Lorem ipsum is saying I need to change this (in addition to changes to saving the transaction) to use the original UTC offset. How would I do that?

```
let hDate = item.entryDT ?? Date()
      Text(hDate.formatted(.dateTime.day().month(.wide).year().hour().minute()))
```

Comment: `Date` is in `UTC` the only way to convert to the original time zone would be to preserve the original time zone in another variable. For consistency you should make sure that are sources are saving in `UTC`

Comment: Is this a common problem? Don't most people want their transaction time to show the original time no matter where they are located?

Comment: Just details, SwiftUI is a one-size fits most style of coding, auto-adjusting timezones is an expectation in most scenarios, think weather, travel, you want to show time in the user's time zone not in the timezone in the database (usually UTC).

Comment: What I want to do is basically what Apple does with the Photos app. Reviewing pictures taken in Germany at my home on the US west coast show the same time as when they were originally taken, not adjusted by nine hours. If a transaction took place in the morning at 10:45 in Europe, I want it to display in my travel app at 10:45 in any other time zone.

Comment: You just have to code that, “Date“ doesn’t save the original time zone it makes all dates utc and SwiftUI displays them based on the current locale, this works for most apps. If you want original time zone you need to save the time zone value somewhere or save the date as something else that isn’t Apple’s date type.

Comment: As for the apple photos app, they likely get the time zone/time from the metadata for the photo. There is so much information there. It probably uses time stamps and skips Apple’s date all together.